# Using selenium to click in a element

Tags: c#, selenium

I'm trying to click on an element with selenium, but I'm unsuccessful ...

The exception is: **element not found**

Site: https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=5527997602115&text=I%27m%20interested%20in%20your%20car%20for%20sale

I want to click in send button...

I tried to inject javascript to try to click the button but without success ...

```
IWebElement el = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id="/action-button-container"/]"));
el.Click();
```

I also tried to click on the 'a' but to no avail.

```
IWebElement el = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id="/action-button"/]"));
el.Click();
```

Comment: Try this: By.Xpath("//a[@id='action-button']") query to find <a> element, or you can try driver.findElement(By.className("button button--simple button--primary")).click();

Comment: @AndrewOrlov If you have an answer, post it as an answer instead of a comment.

Comment: Did you try adding a wait? or anything else?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that your XPath is only reading

```
//*[@id=
```

This is because you are passing in double quotes around the @id value when you should be passing in single quotes.

Try this for your XPath and it should work like a charm:

```
"//*[@id='/action-button-container'/]"
```

Also, if you know what html tag the element is, I would use that instead of *. This will optimize the way that the element is found.